# Azure App Service Alerts Specific for HTTP 302 Response Code

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, http-response-codes, azure-alerts, azure-metrics-advisor

I have a Azure App Service and I want to set up Alerts if the app responds back with HTTP 302(I need to capture this). I know there is a signal called HTTP 3xx but thats too broad because my app does use other 3xx codes in positive scenario. Is there any way to set up Azure alert only based on 302 HTTP Response code ?

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By collecting [AppService HTTP Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs), you can do alert by querying http 302 with kusto.
Just be attention that you would be charged for some fee of logs.